# Change background for each td with tr parent

Tags: html, css

On `.GMDataRow td:hover` I want to change background-color for each td in that tr element. Is this possible only with CSS? I'm trying to do it with CSS only, **I don't need JQuery, JS solutions.**

```
<tr class="GMDataRow">
<td></td>
<td</td>
...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this way

```
tr.GMDataRow:hover td{background:#ccc;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution suggested by Lalji is perfect.

```
tr.GMDataRow:hover td{
      background-color:red;
}
```

- tr.GMDataRow finds the class "GMDataRow" in table rows.
- tr.GMDataRow:hover will activate hover  css for current targeted row.
- tr.GMDataRow:hover td will target all column which are child of active row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change td background on hover  differently ... try this

HTML

```
<table style="width:100%">

    <tr class="GMDataRow">

        <td>ceva</td>

        <td>ceva</td>

        <td>ceva</td>

        <td>ceva</td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

CSS

```
.GMDataRow td:first-child:hover {
    background: yellow;
}

.GMDataRow td:nth-child(2):hover {
    background: pink;
}

.GMDataRow td:nth-child(3):hover {
    background: red;
}

.GMDataRow td:last-child:hover {
    background: blue;
}
```

also take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp , or here  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp maybe it will help you to understand better.