# CSS change multiple elements on hover

Tags: html, css

I want the whole row to change background-color on hover. The HTML is really old and I must leave it as it is. **So I need this done purely in CSS. No JavaScript nor JQuery.** Once I hover on `.GMDataRow td` I also need to trigger (change background) on the same element in another `td`. The order of elements is same in both `td`'s.

Here's the smaller skeleton of code so you understand what im talking about:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>code here</td>
  <td>code here</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Those two tds have identical children elements and the most important, they have same `<tr class="GMDataRow">`. So I was thinking maybe it can be done with `:nth-child()`. I need your suggestions

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30wv0y8m/7/):

And here's the real skeleton:

```
<table class="GMMainTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="GMBodyLeft">
        <table>
          <tr class="GMDataRow" >
            <td>
              xxx
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="GMDataRow">
            <td>
              xxx
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
       </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="GMBodyMid">
        <table>
          <tr class="GMDataRow">
            <td>
              yyy
            </td>
            <td>
              yyy
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="GMDataRow">
            <td>
              yyy
            </td>
            <td>
              yyy
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets so you can style the HTML from top to bottom ( parent > child ) not the other way around. you can style the parent depending on it's child using JQ and so you can't style a `td` from a `row` when hovering a `td` from another `row`

Comment: Not sure I understand this.. but, could you just remove the `tr` selector? See here: https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/30wv0y8m/11/ It would help a great deal if you were more descriptive "another td" isn't that clear.  Can you rephrase to .. "if I hover over A.. I want B to change as well?

Comment: You can not achieve this using CSS, because you do not have “whole rows”, but two completely independent tables displayed next to each other. There is _no_ connection between a row in the left and a row in the right table, that could be used in CSS to select the “corresponding” row. You will need to use JavaScript here.

Comment: @masterfan I gave you my solution here , in your first post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037615/change-background-for-each-td-with-tr-parent/39041068#39041068

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```css
   .hoverTable{
  width:100%; 
  border-collapse:collapse; 
 }
 .hoverTable td{ 
  padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
 }
 
 .hoverTable tr{
  background: #b8d1f3;
 }
 
    .hoverTable tr:hover {
          background-color: #ffff99;
    }
```

```html
<table class="hoverTable">
 <tr>
  <td>Text 1A</td><td>Text 1B</td><td>Text 1C</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Text 2A</td><td>Text 2B</td><td>Text 2C</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Text 3A</td><td>Text 3B</td><td>Text 3C</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```